# d3.js nodes and trees become seperated during transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've noticed that all the tree examples I've found on bl.ocks.org have a problem in which the transitions of the nodes and links aren't really linked. In some cases this doesn't matter, but other times (especially when the node count gets higher) it results in an animation in which the nodes and links seperate from each other.

An example can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762

To trigger the behavior you just need to increase the number of rendered nodes by expanding some of them and then click the root node. You should see the links and nodes diverge during the animation and then converge only once both transitions have finished.

Is there a way to prevent this divergence?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am unable to see the separation. Could you please post more details about your setup (Browser/OS)? Creating a video/gif will also help elucidate the question.

Comment: It happens in (Opera/Chrome/IE/Firefox) on Windows. Haven't tested it on any other OS. I'll get on making a video of it.

Comment: A video clip can now be seen at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSJv0DPI7Fk You should be able to see minor separation between the root node and its edges. This separation isn't always as small as it is here.